# How can I Instantiate an object only for me?

Tags: unity, networking

I am trying to make a multiplayer game, and I want to instantiate/create/spawn an object only for the player's game client.

However, when I instantiate it, it spawns for everyone.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Spell : NetworkBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        //CreateSpell();
    }

    public void CreateSpell()
    {
        var canv = GameObject.Find("Actionbar");
        var btn = Instantiate(spellButton, canv.transform, false);
        btn.SetActive(true);
        btn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(SpellAction);
        btn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = spellImage;
    }
}
```

Here, the `btn` will show for everyone; and I don't want that.

How can I instantiate the object only for the client who creates it?

Comment: Where do you call CreateSpell?

Comment: If you call it in Start() then the Start() will be executed on all clients(because thats how Start() works). If you call it on OnClick for example then it will be called wherever button was clicked. If you want it to be in Start() but only for you, then do something like: If(player.id == someID) { CreateSpell() }. Beware this is unsecure way of spawning objects. Ideally client should ask server to spawn an object for client, so that server knows that this object Really exists, and its not fake hack from client.